# MongoDB How to find out data directory using Java driver

Tags: mongodb-java

I am using an instance of MongoDB with just one node. I would like to write a web service that fsyncs the data files and zips them into a backup folder.

Ideally, I would get the location of the data directory programatically (rather than reading a config file) so I can easily port this from a development to a production machine, where the installation paths differ. Is there any way to do this using the Java driver?

Comment: You are just asking for trouble trying to backup MongoDB that way.  Very likely you will have corrupted files.  That's why the `mongoexport` tool exists.

Comment: Even if I stop the database? I get the impression that just copying the files may be faster?

Comment: Well, use [`mongodump`](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Import+Export+Tools#ImportExportTools-mongodump) then.  Copying the files may be faster, or it may be slower as it may include copying a lot of free space in the files.  But restoring from a file backup only gives you the option of later recreating exactly what you had (configuration and all).  Backing up to portable representation of the database enables possibilities such as merging data later or backing up only certain parts of the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using use admin
db.runCommand({getCmdLineOpts: 1}) as outlined [here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/getCmdLineOpts+command) and then playing with the returned data.

Example return data is

```
{
        "argv" : [
                "mongod",
                "--port",
                "6669",
                "--dbpath=c:\\data\\mongo2",
                "--rest"
        ],
        "parsed" : {
                "dbpath" : "c:\\data\\mongo2",
                "port" : 6669,
                "rest" : true
        },
        "ok" : 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [mongoexport](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Import+Export+Tools#ImportExportTools-mongoexport) to get the data; run it from the production machine and specify the host/port/collection of the development machine. The data can be imported to the production machine using [mongoimport](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Import+Export+Tools#ImportExportTools-mongoimport).

Comment: The development and host machines are not on the same network. I do not need to transfer data from one to the other. It is my application that will trigger the backup. I would rather fsync and compress (not sure how fast mongoexport + compress will take). I looked a lot and there seems to be no way of getting the location of the data directory in a programatic way. I think I will have to do it thru configuration